# Google Apps script web app automatically linked to latest code?

Tags: web-applications, google-apps-script

I created a Google Apps script, I've deployed it with `Publish > Deploy web app` and I'm running it with `script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec?run=ok`.

Each time I do a small modification in the code, I need to **redo** `Publish > Deploy web app` and change `Project version` to `New`.

This is sometimes very annoying because for each small modification, you need to redo this.

Is there a way to make that calling the script from `script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec?run=ok` **automatically** links to the latest version of the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can test the app for the latest code by putting '/dev' in the URL instead of '/exec'
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Click on 'Test web app for your latest code' to grab the link

[image]