# Google Apps Script web app returns a weird error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm making a web app with Google Apps Script.
Here's my code:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return (HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html'));
}
```

Whenever I run this I get this error:

```
Exception: The parameters () don't match the method signature for HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile. (line 2, file "Code")
```

**This is an issue with code, not deployment.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps script web app automatically linked to latest code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141589/google-apps-script-web-app-automatically-linked-to-latest-code)

Comment: @Kos No, it does not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617138/function-not-found-error-when-making-both-get-and-post-requests-to-a-web-app

Comment: @Kos Still no. Compare the error messages.

Comment: Look at it this way: its an issue with code, not deployment

Comment: Perhaps it should be written like this: `return (HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index'));` don't include the extension

Comment: Do you have a duplicate `doGet()` function defined in another script file in your GAS project?

Comment: What if you remove the `.html` extension from the file name?